# Failed prop type: The prop `open` is marked as required in `ForwardRef(Dialog)`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a reactjs application and i have the below code function defined

```
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';

export default function AddTable(props) {
  const { openPopup } = props;


return (
    <Dialog open={openPopup} width="500px" onClose={handleClose}>
      <DialogTitle style={{ backgroundColor: '#2cad23' }}>
        <TitleContainer>
          <Title>Add a new table</Title>
        </TitleContainer>
      </DialogTitle>
)
}
```

i keep getting Failed Prop type error. What is the best way to define the prop?

I followed the Mui.com documentation and did the same exact thing but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You should post the code where you use the `AddTable` component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see the entire codebase but it is possible that the `AddTable` component is not receiving the `props.openPopup`. Try the below example with states. I have added a `button` to simulate the dialog open/close.

```js
import React from "react";
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';

export default function AddTable(props) {

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  
  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  }
  
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleOpen}>Open Dialog</button>
      <Dialog open={open} width="500px" onClose={handleClose}>
        <DialogTitle style={{ backgroundColor: '#2cad23' }}>
        <TitleContainer>
          <Title>Add a new table</Title>
        </TitleContainer>
      </DialogTitle>
    </>
  )
}
```